# drupal 7 plugin for creating multilingual subtitle for jwplayer videos

Tags: 7, media, files

I am using `Drupal 7`, and using [JWPLAYER](http://jwplayer.com/) for my video. Is there any plugin in `Drupal 7` which allows me to create subtitle in multiple language.

I am trying to avoid third party tools (like [dotsub](http://dotsub.com/) etc) where I need to upload my videos to their end in order to make subtitle. Is there any plugin which will help me to create multi language captions for my videos in `Drupal 7`.